# How to pass mui-icon component as props to another component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-component

```
import React from "react";
import "./SideBarPanel.css";
import AddIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Add";
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';

const SideBarIcon = () => {
  return (
    <div class="sidebar-icon group">
      <AddIcon/>
    </div>
  );
};

const SideBarPanel = () => {
  return (
    <div className="sidebar-icons">
      <SideBarIcon />
      <SideBarIcon />
    </div>
    
  );
};

export default SideBarPanel;
```

[image]

I want to pass the ExpandMoreIcon into the second SideBarIcon component.

Comment: Can you say the result you want to become?

Comment: I posted the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pass a component down to a child component via props just like a normal variable. There is one caveat though: when you render it in the child component, you have to ensure it is named with first letter a capital letter.

```js
import React from "react";
import "./SideBarPanel.css";
import AddIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Add";
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';

const SideBarIcon = (props) => {
  const {icon: Icon} = props;
  return (
    <div class="sidebar-icon group">
      {Icon && <Icon />}
      <AddIcon/>
    </div>
  );
};

const SideBarPanel = () => {
  return (
    <div className="sidebar-icons">
      <SideBarIcon />
      <SideBarIcon icon={ExpandMoreIcon} />
    </div>
    
  );
};

export default SideBarPanel;
```

Here I assign `icon` to a new variable `Icon` while destructuring. This is important because `<icon />` will not work because the first letter is not capitalized.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-chandrasekhar-hlpv13?file=/src/App.js)

Source: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized

Answer (score 0):

I would write `<Icon />` as a child of `<SideBarIcon />`. You can have it as optional `child`. Also in this case you would approach [component composition](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html), which is recommended by React.